# Subquery to gather grouped subset with limits

Tags: mysql, subquery, limit

I'm trying to figure out a way to gather a dataset without having to loop 700,000 mysql queries.

I have two tables

`users` with

```
id autoincrement, 
time timestamp, 
username varchar(200), 
email varchar(100), 
ip varchar(20)
```

and `uniq_ip` with

```
ip unique varchar(20), 
most_recent datetime, 
count (int)
```

`users` has 25 million rows and records the activity of users as they work on the site. `uniq_ip` has a list of all the IP numbers and how many times it's listed in users (on trigger update).

At the moment, while daydream coding, I get a list of all the IPs from `uniq_ip` and loop them to get the most recent 2000 records for each of those IPs.  As `uniq_ip` has 700,000 rows, this loop is really nasty, making 700,000 queries total, using

```
select * from users where ip = '$outerloopip' order by `time` desc limit 2000;
```

I'm trying to get a single query that will grab the most recent 2000 listings for each of the IPs.  If 1.2.3.4 is listed 10,000 times, I just want the most recent 2000, based on the time field.

Any ideas how to do it in one query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry about previous answer and re-read and applied updated query.  I missed and thought you wanted only most recent 2000 IP addresses.  Anyhow, this one does ALL IP addresses and limits the total records per IP to 2,000 entries with most recent at the top.  I would ensure you have an index on

(IP,TIME DESC)

Then, try this query.  The critical thing I missed to clarify.  The HAVING clause is applied AFTER any group-by or order-by clause.  So the data is pre-returned in proper order of IP address and date/time DESCENDING, then the @sql variables are applied.  Once the record is qualified and READY to be added to the final result set, the HAVING clause is applied.  At THAT moment, it looks at the sequence counter and says... if its greater than 2000, throw it out and move on to the next record.

By my original query, it was saving everything, then cycling through a second time and kicking out those greater than 2000 which was probably why it was blowing your disk space away.

```
select
      U.*,
      @LastSeq := IF( @LastIP = U.IP, @LastSeq +1, 1 ) as IPSequence,
      @LastIP := U.IP as carryForNextRecord
   from 
      ( select @LastIP := '', @LastSeq := 0 ) sqlvars,
      Users U
   order by
      U.IP,
      U.time DESC
   having 
      IPSequence <= 2000
```

Comment: I'll drop this into mysql the moment the kids have finished eating my all food.  The table expunges all data that is over a year old so that isn't as issue.  The table is 25 million rows at the moment (will level off at about 80 million) but this will only run once a week in order to update Redis ZSET datasets.

Comment: Ill have to put some more drive space in and try again :-)  The query managed to generate 80gb of temp SQL file, from the 11gb users table, before it exhausted the tmp drive :)

Comment: @pedigree, that doesn't sound right... Just for grins, I would test the scenario and change your 2000 count down to say... 50 or 100 just to test the concept of it.

Comment: Hmm, when I drop it down to 20 rows, it only returns 309 rows total when it should be about 1 million. One of the sets of IPs is correct, showing the most recent 20. hehe :-)

Comment: @pedigree, Completely revised answer and query... (with clarification)

Comment: this looks really promising, just one error [Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'having IPSequence <= 2000' at line 11.  I really appreciate your help.  It looks like swapping the orde by and having clauses around might work, its running the query now so I'll let you know the outcome when its done.

Comment: Sorry about the delay but its working great. Thank you.  Its extremely memory hungry and killed the server on the first run so Ive had to split it into 10 queries based on the IP ranges but thats still a lot better than running 700,000 queries :)

Comment: oh, it seems to be only returning 1001 rows with a ipsequence of 2001, so I'll need to check that out.

Comment: @pedigree, so roughly how long IS it taking your to get them done (just for my perception of 25 million rows and 700k IPs :)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ip as IP ,
     (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(time)     FROM users WHERE ip = IP ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 2000) as Time,
     (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(username) FROM users WHERE ip = IP ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 2000) as UserName,
     (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(email)    FROM users WHERE ip = IP ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 2000) as Email
FROM uniq_id
```

Comment: This will give you 1 row for each ip but comma seperated time,username and email